# Simplify expression with assumption that all variables are real

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

I have an expression in which all variables are real. However when I simplify the expression with appropriate assumptions a 'Conjugate' still remains. How can I get rid of this?

Here is my code

```
n = {Cos[t] Sin[p], Sin[t] Sin[p], Cos[p]};
u = {-Sin[t], Cos[t], 0};
v = {-Cos[p] Cos[t], -Cos[p] Sin[t], Sin[p]};

xv[x_, y_, z_] := {x, y, z};(*x vector*)

alpha[x_, y_, z_] := -I*om*xv[x, y, z].n;
beta[x_, y_, z_] := -I*om*xv[x, y, z].u;
gamma[x_, y_, z_] := -I*om*xv[x, y, z].v;

h0ip[i_, x_, y_, 
  z_] := (alpha[x, y, 
      z] (u[[i]] beta[x, y, z] - v[[i]] gamma[x, y, z]) - 
    n[[i]] (beta[x, y, z]^2 - gamma[x, y, z]^2)) (
  1 - alpha[x, y, z]^2/2 - Exp[alpha[x, y, z]] - 
   alpha[x, y, z]*Exp[alpha[x, y, z]])/alpha[x, y, z]^3;(*i=1,2,3*)

h0ic[i_, x_, y_, 
  z_] := (alpha[x, y, 
      z] (v[[i]] beta[x, y, z] - u[[i]] gamma[x, y, z]) - 
    n[[i]] (2 beta[x, y, z] gamma[x, y, z])) (
  1 - alpha[x, y, z]^2/2 - Exp[alpha[x, y, z]] - 
   alpha[x, y, z]*Exp[alpha[x, y, z]])/alpha[x, y, z]^3;(*i=1,2,3*)

Simplify[
 Sin[t]*h0ip[1, x, y, z]*Conjugate[h0ip[2, xs, ys, zs]], 
 Assumptions -> {om \[Element] Reals, t \[Element] Reals, 
   p \[Element] Reals, x \[Element] Reals, y \[Element] Reals, 
   z \[Element] Reals, xs \[Element] Reals, ys \[Element] Reals, 
   zs \[Element] Reals}]
```

And here is the output:

```
((1 + Conjugate[-E^(-I om (zs Cos[p] + 
           Sin[p] (xs Cos[t] + ys Sin[t]))) + 
       I E^(-I om (zs Cos[p] + Sin[p] (xs Cos[t] + ys Sin[t])))
         om (zs Cos[p] + Sin[p] (xs Cos[t] + ys Sin[t])) + 
       1/2 om^2 (zs Cos[p] + Sin[p] (xs Cos[t] + ys Sin[t]))^2]) Sin[
    t] (1 - E^(-I om (z Cos[p] + Sin[p] (x Cos[t] + y Sin[t]))) + 
     I E^(-I om (z Cos[p] + Sin[p] (x Cos[t] + y Sin[t])))
       om (z Cos[p] + Sin[p] (x Cos[t] + y Sin[t])) + 
     1/2 om^2 (z Cos[p] + Sin[p] (x Cos[t] + y Sin[t]))^2) (Sin[
       p] ((y^2 - z^2) Cos[t] - x y Sin[t]) + 
     z Cos[p] (x Cos[2 t] + y Sin[2 t])) (Sin[
       p] (-xs ys Cos[t] + (xs^2 - zs^2) Sin[t]) + 
     Cos[p] (-ys zs Cos[2 t] + xs zs Sin[2 t])))/(om^2 (z Cos[p] + 
     Sin[p] (x Cos[t] + y Sin[t]))^3 (zs Cos[p] + 
     Sin[p] (xs Cos[t] + ys Sin[t]))^3)
```

Comment: try `ComplexExpand[Simplify[expr]]` and it will do it.

Comment: It worked. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, wait... Actually ComplexExpand is not what I want, because it expands the exponential. I just want to simplify Conjugate[ E^(-I om ...)] to Conjugate[ E^(I om ...)]. I could do this by hand, but I want to automatize it. I have no idea why Mathematica does not do this!?

Comment: Basically what I want is that mathematica also simplifyies the following term in the output Conjugate[-E^(-I om (zs Cos[p] + Sin[p] (xs Cos[t] + ys Sin[t]))) + 
  I E^(-I om (zs Cos[p] + Sin[p] (xs Cos[t] + ys Sin[t])))
    om (zs Cos[p] + Sin[p] (xs Cos[t] + ys Sin[t])) + 
  1/2 om^2 (zs Cos[p] + Sin[p] (xs Cos[t] + ys Sin[t]))^2]